MAPVIZ: How to switch from deprecated Bing Maps to a more updated WMTS/Google Maps Satellite provider?
I’m currently using Mapviz in a ROS2 Project to visualize satellite imagery. The default setup relies on Bing Maps, but the service/map layer I’m using is deprecated and shows very outdated imagery:

This road was from 4 years ago (under construction)
Current Site (Google Earth):

I need more up-to-date satellite images for my application.
I’ve tried using a custom WMTS source by following this repository:
MapViz-Tile-Map-Google-Maps-Satellite (GitHub)
However, the repository seems quite old, and I’m unable to specify latitude/longitude for automatically zooming in on the desired location. Instead, I have to manually pan and zoom, which is quite inconvenient.
My main questions are:

How can I properly integrate a newer map provider (e.g., Azure,
Google Maps, or another WMTS source) into Mapviz so I can display
more current satellite imagery?
Is there a recommended approach or configuration for using Google
Maps Satellite (or a similar service) with Mapviz, especially one
that allows specifying lat/long or a bounding box to auto-center?
Has anyone successfully used a custom WMTS or tile service with
Mapviz (ROS1 + Docker) in a way that can easily be updated or
configured?

What I’ve tried so far:

Using the Bing Maps plugin results in very outdated imagery (and the
service is apparently deprecated).

Attempting to adapt the custom WMTS code from the linked GitHub repo,
but it’s too old or doesn’t support automatic latitude/longitude
centering.


Any advice, recent examples, Tutorial, or step-by-step guidance on how to integrate a modern WMTS or a Google Maps Satellite layer into Mapviz would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
